# How do i extract a certain python package from the requirements file into the main docker file?

Tags: python, docker, devops

So i have a base docker file and a main docker file and a requirements.txt file (which contains a package called mslib). The base docker file is inside a folder called devops and the main docker file is in the root of the directory outside . The requirements.txt file is inside the src/pyscripts folder. Now what i usually do is create a base image of the requirements file so that when I am deploying if any changes aren't made to the requirements file I want to make it faster.

The main docker file(whic is outside) it calls the base image which is created from the base docker file(which is inside the devops folder). In requirements file I have mslib which is like a common package , its an external package. So whenever there is a change this package gets upgraded from 1.x to 1.x . I don't want to keep this in the requirements file coz then i will need to update my image again and again if there is any change, and its like a huge requirements list.

So I wanted some guidance/help on how to go about pulling this mslib file out into the main docker file , so that whenever I am creating the base docker file it doesn't get created again

Base Docker File(in the container_base)

```
# creating from python image
FROM python:3.8
RUN apt-get update
ADD ./src/pyscripts/requirements.txt /mlservices/pyscripts/
WORKDIR /mlservices/pyscripts/
# disables root user warning
ENV PIP_ROOT_USER_ACTION=ignore
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
# # installing python libraries
RUN pip3 install -r /mlservices/pyscripts/requirements.txt
```

Requirements.txt file(inside src/pyscripts)

```
PyYAML==5.4.1
requests-aws4auth==1.1.1
elasticsearch==7.9.0
APScheduler==3.9.1
typing_extensions==4.4.0
spacy-transformers==1.2.5
--index-url https://artifactory.svc.aws.gartner.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple
mlslib==0.1.17
urllib3==1.26
Werkzeug==2.2.2
```

Main Docker File(in the root)

```
ARG TARGET_ENV

# Using a base image (has py requirements installed)

ARG MLSERVICE_EXPERTS_BASE_IMAGE=rcd-docker-${TARGET_ENV}.artifactory.svc.aws.gartner.com/mlservices-experts-base:v0.0.1

FROM ${MLSERVICE_EXPERTS_BASE_IMAGE}

RUN apt-get update

# creating required folders

RUN sh -c "mkdir -p /mlservices/pyscripts"

RUN sh -c "mkdir -p /mlservices/resources/properties"

ARG TARGET_ENV

# copying required files

ADD ./src/pyscripts /mlservices/pyscripts/

ADD ./src/resources/properties/${TARGET_ENV} /mlservices/resources/properties

#COPY ./secret.txt /tmp

WORKDIR /mlservices/pyscripts/

# disables root user warning

ENV PIP_ROOT_USER_ACTION=ignore

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# installing python libraries

# RUN pip3 install -r /mlservices/pyscripts/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r mlslib

# Starting application & config is read from gunicorn.conf.py

CMD ["gunicorn", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "wsgi:app"]
```

Folder Structure :
[image: Folder Structure]